# Calling controller function from JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im using Yii framework, i want to call controller function from JS file,

**My ajax code in JS file:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "operator/checkDisabledDates",
    data: {
        id: 1
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("Fail");
    }
});
```

where `checkDisabledDates` is my controller method name, and `operator` is my controller name.

i got wrong formation of url something like,

```
www.example.com/operator/agent/id/4/operator/checkDisabledDates
```

my ajax url just appends at last position of existing url,
i tried different combinations like,

```
url: "/operator/checkDisabledDates"
url: "../operator/checkDisabledDates"
url: "../checkDisabledDates"
```

nothing worked,
but when i use in below syntax it worked,

```
url: "../../checkDisabledDates"
```

Is there anyway to do this without hardcoding dots(.) like this???

Comment: What is the location of the "checkDisabledDates" ? is it below agent? (url=/agent/check..) below the root? (url=/check...). Having / or http:// will make it a path from the root, anything else is relative

Comment: its under operator controller i.e., operator/checkDisabledDates

Comment: using the information above (../../check.. worked + operator/checkdates gives wrong url), it's "www.example.com/operator/agent/checkDisabledDates". So, changing the url in the original code to "/operator/agent/checkDisabledDates" should yield a succesfull call

Comment: How is this related to Yii? Please update our tags appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not using a relative path to call your controller.
Try using your domain as context

```
var domainName = 'yourSite.com'
url: domainName+"operator/checkDisabledDates"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using in my project and it's working for me, please try this -

Define a Global Variable in `JS` file eg. -

```
var url_path = document.location.origin+document.location.pathname;
```

so now you can use like this

`url: url_path+'?r=operator/checkDisabledDates'`

or
`url: url_path+'operator/checkDisabledDates'`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
data = {};
data.r = 'operator/checkDisabledDates';
data.id = 1;

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "index.php",
data: data,
success: function(data) {
    alert('success');
},
error: function(data) {
    alert("Fail");
}
```

});

Always works for me.